# crontab -e is not working

Tags: bash, permissions, scripts, cron

I am testing crobtab with a simple script which runs for every minute (pasted the temp.sh below), But it is not working

```
# Edit this file to introduce tasks to be run by cron.
#
# Each task to run has to be defined through a single line
# indicating with different fields when the task will be run
# and what command to run for the task
#
# To define the time you can provide concrete values for
# minute (m), hour (h), day of month (dom), month (mon),
# and day of week (dow) or use '*' in these fields (for 'any').#
# Notice that tasks will be started based on the cron's system
# daemon's notion of time and timezones.
#
# Output of the crontab jobs (including errors) is sent through
# email to the user the crontab file belongs to (unless redirected).
#
# For example, you can run a backup of all your user accounts
# at 5 a.m every week with:
# 0 5 * * 1 tar -zcf /var/backups/home.tgz /home/
#
# For more information see the manual pages of crontab(5) and cron(8)
#
# m h  dom mon dow   command

* * * * * /home/temp/temp.sh
```

temp.sh

```
backup_dir=`date "+%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S"`
echo $backup_dir >> $PWD/temp.txt
```

Permission details :

```
-rwxrwxrwx 1 temp temp    73 Mar 14 21:55 temp.sh
-rw-rw-r-- 1 temp temp   100 Mar 14 21:59 temp.txt
```

**NOTE** : when I run manually like "/home/temp/temp.sh", It is working and printing the date in temp.txt file

Anyhelp is appreciated. Thanks

LINUX : Ubuntu 18

Comment: Try to add the shebang `#!/bin/sh` as first line of `temp.sh`, Does `/home/temp` is the home directory of the user that running the job?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `crontab -e` file should be:

*/1 * * * * /home/temp/temp.sh

Make sure that temp.sh has execute permission to create temp.txt using `chmod +x temp.sh`.

Also add shebang and cd to the output diirectory in the temp.sh file

```
#!/bin/sh
backup_dir=`date "+%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S"`
cd /home/temp/
echo $backup_dir >> $PWD/temp.txt
```

Comment: temp.sh is a executable file and added shebang didn't help, I only see the following entries in the /var/log/syslog I see the following log in the /var/log/syslog without any error for every one minute LOG : Mar 14 22:49:01 Host-Temp CRON[15277]: (temp) CMD (/home/dominic/finalewd/temp.sh) - I don't know the meaning of it

Comment: did you add the `cd /home/temp/` that I mentioned?

Comment: ya its working, what is the significance of cd command in this cron?

Comment: Well, the default output directory is the user's home folder, which in your case should be `/home/dominic/`(guessing from the cron log). So since you are logged in as dominic, the temp.txt file should have been generated in `/home/dominic/`. Adding the cd just changed the `$PWD` to this new directory

Comment: I modified the answer. I had it right, but lost track when the first * got read as bullets on stackoverflow.

Comment: OK but even so, the OP's original `* * * * *` is equivalent and is not a reason for failure

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked whether `/etc/cron.allow` exists? In this case, user "temp" has to be listed in there. Apart from that, `/var/log/syslog` should contain any related error/status messages.

Comment: /etc/cron.allow is not available

Comment: Also I see the following log in the /var/log/syslog without any error for every one minute Mar 14 22:49:01 Host-Temp CRON[15277]: (temp) CMD (/home/dominic/finalewd/temp.sh) - I don't know the meaning of it

Comment: The above log message tells you that cron is trying to execute the mentioned script in a subdirectory of "dominic"'s home directory every minute using the credentials of user "temp" (note the discrepancy dominic<>temp). This means that there has to be an entry in either "temp"'s crontab or in `/etc/crontab`.